# Replace %~db1 using SET

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I'm trying to replace a string passed as an argument to a batch file.

This works:

```
set PWD="%~dp1"
set "PWD=%PWD:\=/%"
```

Which puts the passed argument's parent directory path inside `PWD` variable, and then replaces `\` characters to `/` characters.

Is there a way to achieve this one liner by execution of just *one command* instead of two?

Something like this: `set "PWD=%~dp1:\=/%`, however, that doesn't obviously work.

Please elaborate both methods, using `DelayedExpansion` and not using it.

Comment: Technically, the `%PWD%` variable will contain the parent path of the first parameter/argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you test this before posting it?

Your code will produce

```
PWD=\=/
```

If it produces the "correct result" then it's because you're not clearing `pwd` at the end of each run (usually by a `setlocal` directly after the `@echo off`) and hence the result will be *NOT* of the current `%~dp1` but of the previous setting of `pwd`.

Your code first sets `pwd` to be `"c:\whatever..."` (including the quotes) PLUS the <kbd>Space</kbd> before the `&` and then sets `pwd` again to *the prior value of pwd* with `\` replaced by `/`.

`cmd` will resolve any expression involving `%var%` first, and **then** executes the result. With `delayedexpansion`, `!var!` is evaluated at *run-time* and `%var%` at *parse-time*.

Since string-manipulation is not allowed on `metavariables`, the required operation cannot be condensed into a single statement; the value must be passed through an ordinary environment variable first.

To fix your statement, use

```
set "PWD=%~dp1" & CALL set "PWD=%%PWD:\=/%%"
```

which will perform the string-manipulation in a subshell after first assigning the value to `pwd` - moving the quote delimits the command that will be executed - following spaces after the closing quote will **not** be included in the value assigned.

Comment: Thanks, you also referenced the space character issue I was having. I'm a bit disappointed having to resort to a `CALL` to manipulate the variables correctly, though it seems to work as expected. I appreciate the explanation!